# Как сделать программу, которая будет повторять текст столько раз, сколько попросил пользователь?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например текст "Hello World!". Пользователь ввёл число 5, и "Hello World!" высветилось 5 раз. Ввёл 10, высветилось 10 раз. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 7):

```
a = int(input("Введите целое число"))
for _ in range(a):
    print('Hello World!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Строки можно умножать с помощью оператора `*`.

***Пример:***

```py
s = 'Hello World!'
n = 5  # int(input())

print(s * n)
```

***stdout:***

```py
Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример через цикл.

```
# переменная, хранящая строку
message = input('Введите строку: ')
# количество повторений
count = int(input('Введите число: '))

for i in range(count):
    print(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Цикл for

```
num = int(input('Сколько раз повторять: '))
for i in range(num):
    print('Text')
```

Цикл While

```
num = int(input('Сколько раз повторять: '))
i = 1
while i<=num:
    i+=1
    print('Text')
```

как удобней)